# Leaflet.Snap can't snap a polyline to guideLayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I try to snap a polyline point on a guideLayer when drawing new polylines. My mouse snap to the guideLayer when I'm approaching it, but I can't add a new point on the guideLayer.

My map and controls declarations are the following :

```
var mymap = L.map('map').setView([46.658, 7.011], 14);
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();         
var mymap.addLayer(this.drawnItems);
var tracksGeoJson = L.geoJSON(listTracks).addTo(mymap);
var guideLayers = [tracksGeoJson];

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw();
var drawControl.initialize({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems 
        },
    draw: {
        polygon: false,
        circle: false,
        rectangle: false,
        marker: false,
        polyline: {guideLayers: display.guideLayers, snapDistance: 10}
    }
});
mymap.addControl(this.drawControl);
```

I'm using Leaflet v1.0.3, Leaflet.draw v0.49 and Leaflet.Snap v0.0.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

It was the "snapDistance" option that didn't work well for the polyline. So the new drawControl initialization is :

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw();
var drawControl.initialize({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems 
        },
    draw: {
        polygon: false,
        circle: false,
        rectangle: false,
        marker: false,
        polyline: {guideLayers: display.guideLayers}
    }
});
mymap.addControl(this.drawControl);
```

And now I can add polyline point on other polyline.